# What are methods definitions in object literals and when to use them?

Tags: javascript, methods, object-literal

If I have the following object literal, I understand that `val` and `prop` are **properties** of the **obj** object.

```js
const obj = {
  val: 7,

  prop: function() {
    alert("prop " + this.val);
  },

  met() {
    alert("met " + this.val);
  }
};

obj.prop();
obj.met();
```

Property `prop` holds a reference to an anonymous function. Such a property is also referred to as a **method**.

In Visual Studio IntelliSense:

- `prop` is referred to as **property**,
- `met` is referred to as **method**.

But

1. What is `met`?
2. How does it differ from `prop`?
3. When to use `prop` syntax and when `met`?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Actually, that doc says, mysteriously... "However, note that the method syntax is not equivalent to a normal property with a function as its value — there are semantic differences".  I think that last phrase is at the heart of your question.

Comment: Methods are non-constructable, i.e. they cannot be used with `new`. Other than that, it comes down to preference. Your `function` is also not anonymous; see [How does an anonymous function know its name?](/q/73804138/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I wouldn't say it's up to preference. Unless you *need* a `function`, method definition syntax is cleaner, more straightforward, slightly more efficient (doesn't allocate a prototype object) and should be preferred.